# why my ajax control doesn't work, even no error?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

i ahve tried what ever i can to put ajax calender extender in project but it doesn't show, calender never appears,

why ?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScrptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:CalendarExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

no error, 1st i download ajaxtoolkit for .net 4.5 then i added AJAX tab to tools then i right clicked AJAX tab and selected CHOOSE ITEMS and added these tools to project and then this code

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the scriptManager in the page with

`<Ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>` .

This will certainly solve your problem.

Comment: bro, i have done that already and please propose some new solutions